# Is there any way to create a single class diagram for whole project(Java) in Enterprise Architect or In Visio?

Tags: java, class, uml, visio, enterprise-architect

I'm working on creating a class diagram for the whole project. is there any process to create a single class file comprising all the related modules or it should be done manually?.

Comment: I think you need to use BlueJ IDE.

Comment: but my client need it in an enterprise architect project file. Does BlueJ IDE have EA support?

Comment: You mean to RE your project? If so: just give it a try and see what Package/Code Engineering/Import delivers.

Comment: By doing that I'll get class diagram for individual packages, but I need it for whole project in one single diagram with/without connectors

Comment: Is there any way to do the same in Vizio.?

Comment: @SriTejaKumarSamudrala do a separate question, but im pretty sure a question would already exist for this. And correct me if im wrong, but Eclipse or Netbeans have class diagram generation capabilities